# Turing Halting Problem vs. Unrestricted Turing Test

Tags: information-theory

Consider the halting problem. Does anyone know or can maybe speculate why Turing proposed a Turing Test when the halting problem had already in principle answered the question of the Turing test?  If it is possible as the halting problem proposes to write a program that will create a loop on any Universal Turing Machine without the machine detecting it then why not feed the program to the conversation to the unrestricted Turing test "booth occupant".? That would be a simple way to tell if the occupant was a computer.  Unless you can build a machine that is not a subset of a universal Turing machine then there is no validity to the Turing test. If you speculate that someone someday can build a "human thinking" machine then that is not my question. In terms of what was then and is now know I don't see why Turing proposed the Turing test because his own work on the halting problem already answered his question. This point always bothered me so maybe someone with more background can shed a little light.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you pass a program to the occupant of the booth in the Turing Test, the result will not be the occupant running the program, it will be "What the heck is this?" or "No, I will not run your program indefinitely".  A machine is just as capable of giving these responses as a person is.

Comment: I accept your response.  It could even be a random response.  If I look at it that way then I have no problem since the Halting problem developed by Turing seems to be a stronger test.  If any computer is given the halting problem it will go in a loop. Mathematically proven to be unsolvable by any subset of a Universal Turing Machine and all computers are Turing machines. At least everyone that exists so far. ;)